# Bevel is wonky, applying scale won't fix it

Tags: bevel, scale

[image][image]

I can't for the life of me figure why the bevel tool acts like this (bevel is uneven, left side of the frame is more beveled than the right), first I tried making the door frame from a cube using extrusions and subdivisions, then with copying vertices and connecting them, then with a mix of the previous methods with the addition of knife tool and lastly making it from a plane trying all sorts of things. Yet still the "left" side bevels more. It's like it somehow gravitates more to the left. I've made sure a that I've selected symmetrically the edges I want to bevel.

-I've applied the scale so all axes XYZ are 1

-I've selected and re-selected the edges to make sure that it's not about that.

-I've recalculated normals (if that had something to do with it.)

-I've constructed the object from scratch few times using different methods to eliminate the mistake I've probably made at some point.

Every time the same problem persists. I know it's something simple, I just can't see what it is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see differences in the topology between the two parts (look for example the small edge on the lower face). Can you show the mesh before the beveling?

Comment: Images are added to the original post. I had to make another one to show the mesh. And the same problem persist, I really don't believe I can make a same mistake over and over again using different techniques. I've checked the vertices, there are only 24 vertices, 12 on both sides (X is the axis of symmetry), their positions are correct. I can see no reason why the other side isn't beveling the same amount. The scaling would otherwise be the answer, but I have checked that already.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue, in my testfile your geometry is being beveled [symmetrically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5eYk.gif). Could you upoload the unbeveled version of the object to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: I had to put this here, because of my low reputation I can't post more than two links, and those are the images seen on the original post https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4018/ I'm fairly certain this is a settings/user(me) issue rather than a mesh issue. NOTE: this isn't the original object, I made a new object to post this link.

Comment: Even with your testfile, I am not able to experience the a-simmetry. All works fine. You can try to record a video of the action. I suggest to substitute the lower image with one showing the tool parameters you are using.

Comment: Any suggestions about the recording? I don't have any software or are you saying that it is possible to do it in Blender?

Comment: You can follow the advices told in the 2nd point of: [How do I ask a question that is hard to describe?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-is-hard-to-describe/609#609)

Comment: [Here's the gif](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/UniformAbleIcefish) Funny thing is that it's symmetrical when I bevel too far.. I managed to bevel the object one edge at a time to my satisfaction, though I still want to solve this, because this might repeat itself in the future.

Comment: I see, but I'm sorry: I can't still figure it out. Did you try that on a different computer? Are you using the latest stable release 2.79? One last thing you can try is to record a video of you building from scratch the object in a new file so we can see exactly each move you make.

Comment: Upgrading to 2.79 seem to have done the trick. My version was 2.78a. I hope the problem does not reappear. I sincerely thank you for your time, Carlo, and for your willingness to help solving the problem.

Comment: Gald I somehow helped. Let us know if the problem reappears.